# Can't connect client to docker python server

Tags: python, docker, connection-refused

I am trying to connect python server running under docker (compose) and getting "Connection Refused" error on Ubuntu. Any help appreciated.

Command to build my server using docker compose:

```
sudo docker-compose up -d
```

client trying to connect using curl: (192.168.1.149 is the static IP of Ubuntu machine), I have tried with 127.0.0.1 and IP address of docker image and 0.0.0.0 without making any differences.

```
curl --data "Testing" 192.168.1.149:5149
```

Response from curl command:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.1.149 port 5149: Connection refused
```

dockerfile_test:

```
FROM python:3.8
EXPOSE 5149
COPY ./test_main.py /
CMD ["python", "-u", "./test_main.py"]
```

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  test_expose:
    build:
      context: /home/home/mydockers/custom_docker/test_expose_port
      dockerfile: dockerfile_test
    image: test_expose
    container_name: test_expose
    ports:
      - 5149:5149
    restart: unless-stopped
```

test_main.py:

```
import socket
import time

socket_receive_buffer = 4096

def main():
    try:
        print("Create socket")
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        print("Bind socket")
        sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 5149))
        while True:
            print("In loop waiting for data")
            data, address = sock.recvfrom(socket_receive_buffer)
            print("received data")
            string_data = data.decode('utf-8')
            print(string_data)
    except Exception as e:
        print("got error")
        if sock is not None:
            sock.close()
        print("Exception " + str(e))
        time.sleep(60)

main()
```

Comment: Why do you use `sudo` with `docker-compose`?

Comment: please add the output from `docker ps` and `docker logs CONATINER`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running a UDP server, so:

1. Your port-forwarding needs to be a UDP port-forward, by default it's TCP.
2. `curl` is sending a HTTP request, which runs over TCP. So `curl` will never be able to talk to your server.

Beyond those two issues that need fixing, I would also suggest:

1. Don't use UDP, there's usually no reason to use it.
2. Don't write a custom network protocol, there's usually not reason to do that. Just build something on top of HTTP.
3. If you do need to do one or the other, use a networking framework (Twisted, Tornado, asyncio) that will make all this much simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the details.
I added udp in port forwarding and used my own python client and all started working as expected. Appreciate you help.

Port forwarding line changed to:
- 5149:5149/udp

And python client file test_client.py:
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.sendto("Test data string".encode("utf-8"), ("192.168.1.149", 5149))